# Find all substring in a string

Tags: c#, regex

Hi guys I have a string like that:

```
example(string1,string2,string3)
```

And I need to extract all the parameters. I used this regex `^(.*?\()` but it checks only the text in the brackets.
As results I expected to have:

```
string1
string2
string3
```

Comment: Your question is really unclear, are you saying you have a *string* like `example(string1,string2,string3,string4)` and want to extract the parameters from it?

Comment: @James sorry, now I edit the answer

Comment: What is your expected results?

Comment: @Kaf sorry edit again...

Comment: @Tinwor this could actually end up being a fairly complex Regex because there are a number of things you need to take into consideration, `String.Substring` might be easier in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one pair of braces then you can get it directly by `Regex.Match()` method like below :

```
string str = "example(string1,string2,string3) and test(string4)"
string[] params = Regex.Match(str, @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[1].Value.Split(',');
```

But, If you have multiple parameters with multiple braces then you need to get `MatchCollection` first using `Regex.Matches()` method and then iterate it in loop to get all parameters like below :

```
string str = "example(string1,string2,string3) and test(string4)"
List<string> params = new List<string>();
MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(str, @"\(([^)]*)\)");

for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
{
   params.AddRange(collection[i].Groups[1].Value.Split(',').ToList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @UpendraChaudhari but I prefer use regex because I think it's more clear

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
string[] result = str.TrimStart(@"example(").TrimEnd(@")").Split(",");
```

the result array will be

```
string1
string2
string3
```

Comment: I think it's pretty clear from the question that hardcoding the "function name" into the search is not a valid option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex:

```
\((?:(?<param>[\w\d]+)[,\s]*)+\)
```

with the result:

[image: Regex result]

so you have parameters as captures of the first group (named `param`).

Comment: This will only match the last parameter

Comment: @James, it will match whole `(...)` with all parameters as captures, I even provided working result.